# Plumbing equivalent of 'git diff REVISION'

Tags: git

`git diff` respects `color.ui=always`, among other things. Is there an equivalent plumbing command that will always give me a valid unified diff that I can apply using `patch`?

Comment: adding `--no-color` as an option is not good enough?

Comment: @eftshift0: it's not the preferred method since it's still susceptible to current and future user configuration settings. Sometimes there's no good plumbing-command alternative, but here there is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git diff` runs one of:

- `git diff-tree`: to compare two internal tree objects (or more than two for a combined diff), e.g., for commit-vs-commit in `git diff <hash1> <hash2>`
- `git diff-index`: to compare one internal tree object to the index or the work-tree, e.g., for `git diff <hash>` or `git diff --cached HEAD`
- `git diff-files`: to compare the index to the work-tree

Since you mention `git diff <rev>` you're getting `git diff-index`.  Use that—it's a plumbing command—with whichever options you want here, probably `-p`.